# Passing a Django Statement or Accessing specific query set index

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to return the number of threads and posts that belong to that specific forum. The structure is like this: Category -> Forum -> Thread.
[image: Structure]

I want to query the database for all threads and posts that belong to that Forum.

This is my current code:

Models.py

```py
class Forum(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='forums')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Thread(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    thread_forum = models.ForeignKey(Forum, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Post(models.Model):
    post_body = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    post_thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + ' | ' + str(self.author)
```

Views.py

```py
class HomeView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'name'
    template_name = 'index.html'
    queryset = Category.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['thread_count'] = Thread.objects.all().count()
        context['post_count'] = Post.objects.all().count()
        context['user_count'] = User.objects.all().count()
        context['categorys'] = Category.objects.all()
        context['newest_user'] = User.objects.order_by('-id')[0]

        return context
```

index.html

```
{% for forum in category.forums.all %}
    <div class="container-fluid category-forums clearfix"> <!-- 3 red -->
        <div class="container-fluid category-forums-wrap d-flex align-items-center"> <!-- 4 green -->
            <div class="container-fluid forum-details-wrapper clearfix">
                <div class="container-fluid forum-details-container">
                    <p class="forum-name"><a href="{% url 'threadlist' forum.pk %}">{{ forum.name }}</a>
                    </p>
                    <p class="forum-desc">{{ forum.description }}</p>

                    <div class="sub-forum-container container clearfix">
                        <p class="sub-forums clearfix">{{ forum.category }}</p>
                        <p class="sub-forums clearfix">Sub-Category 2</p>
                        <p class="sub-forums clearfix">Sub-Category 3</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="container-fluid forum-threads clearfix">
                <div class="forum_threads_count">
                    100
                </div>
                <div class="forum_threads_threads">
                    <span>Threads</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid forum-posts clearfix">
                <div class="forum_posts_count">
                    100
                </div>
                <div class="form_posts_text">
                    <span>Posts</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid forum-latest-posts clearfix">

                <?php echo '<span class="last_thread"><a href=viewthread.php?id=''>Last Post</a></span>
                <?php echo "<span class='last_post_by'>by Taz</span>
                <span class="last_post">Last Post</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I wish I could do this inside index.html but I can't: `{{ Thread.filter(forum=forum).count()) }}`

Got any ideas for a simple way to incorporate this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="forum_posts_count">
   {{ forum.thread | length }}
</div>
```

Try this